# Script should wait till browser is closed manually

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber

I am using Java for selenium automation
I have a scenario where I need to should move to next scenario in cucumber feature file only when I close the chrome browser manually for the current scenario.

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please provide some code and the error you are getting so we can help.

Answer (score 6):

You can also do like this

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    waitForDriverToClose(driver);
```

**waitForDriverToClose**

```
private static void waitForDriverToClose(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    try {
                        driver.getTitle();
                        return true;
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println("Couldn't Connect Driver / Driver Closed");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }));
        } catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException ex) {
            System.out.println("Timeout Trying Again");
            waitForDriverToClose(driver);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,   waitForDriverToClose(driver) method helped me

Comment: Then you can [accept it as an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) as it would help others

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like looping until you got browser died or not reachable exception..

```
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    Boolean check = false;

    while (!check) {

        try {
            driver.getTitle();
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //you can verify correct exception here ie not reachable, dead etc..
            check = true;
        }

    }

    System.out.println("after browser close");
    //continue your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

If you manually close the browser while your selenium tests are running you will get:
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Window not found. The browser window may have been closed.

You could try and catch this exception and then go from there.

Comment: @madhan Thanks a lot,   waitForDriverToClose(driver) method helped me