# How to use Selenium in Java and wait until browser closed manually

Tags: java, selenium

I need to use Selenium WebDriver in Java. Instead of closing the driver with `driver.close()`, I have to wait until the user close the browser manually. How can I do it?

I have read [Selenium - Script should wait till browser is closed manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093559/selenium-script-should-wait-till-browser-is-closed-manually), but it didn't work because there is no WebDriverWait. I'm using Selenium 2.52.0 and Firefox 45.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by - "it didn't work because there is no WebDriverWait"

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.